# Testing significant difference between two independent means

Tags: statistical-significance, mean, spss

I have two groups within a dataset. One group completed one 10-point Likert, the other completed a similar but different 10-point Likert. Beyond simple descriptives, I'd like to identify whether one measure is significantly higher/lower than the other. What the most straightforward way to do this?

I've been trying to run an independent t-test with survey version as the grouping variable, but SPSS keeps giving me the error: t cannot be computed because at least one of the groups is empty. Am I structuring this wrong? Thanks.